# two loop execute and the 2nd cannot to be executed

Tags: oracle

I have 2 Cursor and loop it ,where the 2nd loop doesn't execute. there is not start group print in log.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_org_user_group_ref_migration(systemFlag in varchar2)
    as       
        Cursor org_user_cursor IS
        select id,new_id
        from org_user_ns;      
        org_user_row org_user_cursor%rowtype ;

        Cursor org_group_cursor is
        select id,new_id
        from org_group_ns;

     org_group_row org_group_cursor%rowtype ;

    BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('start user');      
        for org_user_row in org_user_cursor 
        LOOP 
           dbms_output.put_line(org_user_row.new_id|| ','  || org_user_row.id);
        END LOOP;   
        dbms_output.put_line('start group');
       FOR org_group_row in org_group_cursor 
       LOOP 
        dbms_output.put_line(org_group_row.new_id || ','|| org_group_row.id);
       END loop;   
    commit;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

that's log out print issue,

add dbms_output.enable(NULL); after begin, it's okay,